# change partially memory_limit and max_execution_time

Tags: php, memory, time, limit, execution

I have a memory_limit problem and a max execution time problem doing a complex query in a huge database.

The easy way to solve it would be to increase the value of these parameters in php.ini, but I have been reading and it's not recommended and splitting the query is not possible too.

So, are there any way to modify these parameters or increase their just for some requests?

Thanks

Comment: The easy way to increase the value is running `ini_set()` in your script, not editing the system wide settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function for this, It sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','16M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Read [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) regarding description of core php.ini directives